# Does watch only monitor the visible output?

Tags: watch

Does `watch` only monitor the visible output of a command? Say I'm in a directory with the following contents:

```
$ ls
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n
```

If I run `watch -g ls -1` I expect it to exit if a file is added or removed. What actually happens is that it exits *only* if the file in question is visible in the terminal output of `watch`:

```
$ watch -g ls -1
Every 2.0s: ls -1                   Wed Nov 13 16:35:03 2013

a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Deleting the file `m`, which is not visible because of the size of my terminal, does nothing. Deleting a visible file, say `d`, causes `watch` to exit as expected.

The `-g` flag is explained thusly in my `man` page:

```
   -g, --chgexit
          Exit when the output of command changes.
```

What's going on? Is this normal? How can I use `watch` for commands with long output? I am using `watch from procps-ng 3.3.4` which was installed from the Debian repos.

Comment: What does the `-g` option to `watch` do? I don't find it in my version of `watch`

Comment: @1_CR see updated question, it should cause it to exit when the output changes. It does work as advertised when the change is visible on the screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this thread titled: [Bug#225549: have watch monitor stderr](http://us.generation-nt.com/bug-225549-have-watch-monitor-stderr-help-168081331.html). That thread is from 2008, but it looks like older versions don't support the watching of anything other than STDOUT.

So we're limited to just STDOUT. As for visible there is a lot of language in the `info watch` and `man watch` that make me think your
observation/assumption is correct.

*excerpt*

```
   watch runs command repeatedly, displaying its output (the first screen‐
   full).   This  allows you to watch the program output change over time.
   By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use -n or --interval to
   specify a different interval.
```

Also this bit under BUGS:

```
BUGS
       Upon  terminal resize, the screen will not be correctly repainted until
       the next scheduled update.  All --differences highlighting is  lost  on
       that update as well.
```

If I had to guess I'd think they were storing the visible bits in a buffer between runs, and then analyzing just those characters.

#### EDIT #1

I debugged this further using `strace` and you can see `watch` reading the output from the `ls` command so it's internally dropping the change.

*before I delete the `m` file*

```
$ strace -o w.log watch -g 'ls -1'
read(3, "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\nk\nl\nm\nn\nw.lo"..., 4096) = 34
close(3)                                = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
munmap(0x7f4da83af000, 4096)            = 0
wait4(31011, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 31011
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4da79b94a0}, {0x7f4da7f81ee0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4da79b94a0}, 8) = 0
write(1, "\33[H\33[2JEvery 2.0s: ls -1\33[1;140H"..., 119) = 119
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x7f4da7f81ee0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4da79b94a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({2, 0}, NULL)                 = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4da839f9d0) = 31014
close(4)                                = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4da83af000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(3, "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\nk\nl\nm\nn\nw.lo"..., 4096) = 34
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4da83af000, 4096)            = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

*after the `m` file is deleted*

```
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4da79b94a0}, {0x7f4da7f81ee0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4da79b94a0}, 8) = 0
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=0, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "\33[1;158H8\33[11;163H", 18)  = 18
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x7f4da7f81ee0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4da79b94a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({2, 0}, NULL)                 = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4da839f9d0) = 31028
close(4)                                = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4da83af000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(3, "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\nk\nl\nn\nw.log\n", 4096) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
munmap(0x7f4da83af000, 4096)            = 0
wait4(31028, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 31028
```

Comment: Yeah, it just seems weird, it makes it impossible to run something like `watch -g foo; echo "Something changed!"`. It seems a strangely crippling bug in such an established program.

Comment: @terdon - my ancient version of Fedora didn't have the `-g` switch but I tried it on Ubuntu and it behaves the same.

Comment: OK, that's _really_ weird then. So it does actually monitor and see the change, it just doesn't react to it! Definitely a bug then.

Answer (score 2):

> I expect it to exit if a file is added or removed

I'm pretty sure you're after [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#wiki-getting).

My manpage for *watch*, from *procps-ng*, says

> watch runs command repeatedly, displaying its output and errors **(the first screenfull)**.

Comment: That's not what he's asking about, he's trying to understand the behavior of an update occurring, being displayed via STDOUT, but isn't visible in the terminal b/c he's re-sized it so that the output that is being changed is "off screen". Most everyone I've discussed this with today would've expected `watch` to behave as the OP, and exit with the change.

Comment: Yes we've already discussed that too, I highlighted that same text in my answer. I know Terdon fairly well and at this point he wants to know the reason why.

Comment: I agree it's not the answer to his question, but it's the solution to his problem.

Comment: You mean using inotify? That's not what he's after, he wants to know why `watch` behaves this way. He knows about inotify.

Comment: That's his question.  What he's trying to do with it is what I quoted: wait for a file to be added or removed.  Watch isn't the tool for that job.

Comment: Yeah, my point is how is this any different than what I said?

Comment: It isn't, I agree with what you said.  But he's coming looking for how to do something he's decided is the solution to his real problem, when it isn't.

Comment: jthill, thanks but as @slm said my real question here is why this is happening. It seems like a crippling bug for such an established program and renders the `-g` flag useless if it only exits on visible changes. I am using `ls` as an example, my original use case was watching the output of a command that prints a few hundred lines. I wanted it to exit and continue on to the next command if the output changed. _inotify_ is great but won't help with that.

Comment: @terdon then what's wrong with cmp-in-a-loop?  `cmd>last;while cmd>this; do cmp last this; rc=$?; mv this last; test $rc -ne 0 && break; sleep 2; done`  hardly seems worth writing watch to do that.

Comment: @jthill because 1) I am wondering why `watch` behaves like that and I consider it a bug (and have filed a bug report), it should not behave that way 2) As you can see, what you just wrote is _far_ more complex than using `watch -g command; 2ndcommand` 3) `watch` is a basic tool and part of the `procps` package, it should work as advertized.