# Open a text file in a terminal and auto-refresh it whenever it is changed

Tags: terminal, text

How do I open a text file in a terminal with instant auto-refresh every time it is changed?

I've looked at `vim` with `:set autoread`, but it requires some elementary input (such as a keypress inside `vim`) to trigger the refresh.

I want the auto-refresh to be hands-free. Is there some hack to do this?

I'm using Crunchbang 11, but I'm quite comfortable with the terminal.

Comment: What is that good for? What is this file about? If it is a log, it usually has new lines added to the bottom, then you could just use `tail -f $file`.

Comment: Specifically, I am writing a Python script which writes out another text file, not just add new lines at the bottom. I'd like to monitor that text file.

Comment: inotify.......?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `inotify`. Looking it up, it's an API that I need to access with C programming, which I'm not inclined to do anytime soon. I'm looking for a shell command solution.

Comment: google -> py inotify "Pyinotify is a Python module for monitoring filesystems changes. Pyinotify relies on a Linux Kernel feature (merged in kernel 2.6.13) called inotify. inotify is an event-driven notifier, its notifications are exported from kernel space to user space through three system calls. pyinotify binds these system calls and provides an implementation on top of them offering a generic and abstract way to manipulate those functionalities."

Comment: There is a suite of tools you can use from the command line called, typically, `inotify-tools`. These use a feature built into the Kernel called inotify. Any time a file is acted upon an event is sent via inotify that you can act on. Many prog. langs. such as Python, Perl, etc. have libraries that wrap the Inotify API. See the Wikipedia pg: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should show you the file once per second:

```
watch -n 1 cat file
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks! I extended it further with `watch -tpcn 1 pygmentize -g filename`

Comment: @Kit careful with `watch -g`, it doesn't work [as you would expect](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101041/22222).

Comment: @terdon, the `-g` switch is actually for `pygmentize`. Anyway, thanks for the warning.

Comment: If the file content is over one page, using this, you cannot scroll the screen to check the rest of the content of the file.

Comment: If you want another part of the file to be shown you can get creative with `head` and/or `tail`, for example getting the last part only would be something like `watch -n 1 cat file | tail`

Comment: Why not just `watch -n 1 tail file`?

Comment: You're right, that's better!

Answer (score 21):

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Shows the syslog updates as they are added to the file.

Comment: This shows lines as they are added correct? OP needs a full refresh.

Comment: works on windows with git-bash too

Comment: that's irrelevant answer because that command showing only newly added lines, but the question is how to see _any_ changes in file

Answer (score 3):

I would use `watch` as the other answer suggests but just to show you how one can approach a seemingly complicated problem using the building blocks provided by a shell such as Unix; a while loop can be a simple way to perform your looping.

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do clear; date; cat <afile>; sleep 1 ;done
```

#### Example

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do clear; date; cat sample.txt; sleep 1 ;done
Fri Nov 15 09:17:39 EST 2013
1
2
3
4
5
```

The screen clears and then after a second, this gets displayed:

```
Fri Nov 15 09:17:40 EST 2013
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, you could also use `inotify` though it is overkill. By far the simplest is to use `watch`. Here's one way to do it with `inotify`:

1. Install the `inotify-tools` package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
   ```
2. Use `inotifywatch` to check your file for changes. Run it in a loop and `cat` the file if a change is detected (that's why I `grep` for the string `total`):

   ```
   while true; do 
     inotifywatch -e modify -t 1 kk 2>/dev/null | grep -q total && 
     echo "$(date;cat kk)"; 
   done
   ```

Comment: Passing `-q` (or `--quiet`) to `grep` will silence the matched line with "total".

Comment: @FichteFoll good point (please disregard my previous comment if you saw it before I deleted, I was being slow). Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

`watch(1)` is a really useful tool. [[1]](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tag/watch-command)

I would not recommend using `cat` though.

Instead, use `head` or `tail` for whether you need to see the beginning or the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the new lines being appended to a file that has more than one page
I recommend to use

```
watch -n 1 tail -n 50 log.txt
```

watch -n 1 will show updates at every 1 second and tail -n 50 will show last 50 lines and in combination this will result in a automatic display of last 50 lines of log.txt that refreshes every 1 second